# Java Stringbuilder.replace

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Consider the following inputs:

```
String[] input = {"a9", "aa9", "a9a9", "99a99a"};
```

What would be the most efficient way whilst using a StringBuilder to replace any digit directly prior to a nine with the next letter after it in the alphabet?

After processing these inputs the output should be:

```
String[] output = {"b9", "ab9", "b9b9", "99b99a"}
```

I've been scratching my head for a while and the StringBuilder.setCharAt was the best method I could think of.

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: And what's the problem with this method, if it works as intended?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a regex...

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Yes you can, pls see my answer below.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sure, you can do it with a regex if you use a `Matcher` to build the result incrementally; I assumed you meant with a single `replaceAll` call.

Comment: Indeed. Don't know why you'd want to use regex for something as simple as this, especially when the code to do so is longer than the code to do without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have to look at every character, you'll never perform better than linear in the size of the buffer. So you can just do something like

```
for (int i=1; buffer.length() ++i) // Note this starts at "1"
    if (buffer.charAt[i] == '9')
        buffer.setCharAt(i-1, buffer.getCharAt(i-1) + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can following code:

```
String[] input = {"a9", "aa9", "a9a9", "99a99a", "z9", "aZ9"};
String[] output = new String[input.length];
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("([a-z])(?=9)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
    Matcher mt = pt.matcher(input[i]);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    while (mt.find()) {
        char ch = mt.group(1).charAt(0);
        if (ch == 'z') ch = 'a';
        else if (ch == 'Z') ch = 'A';
        else ch++;
        mt.appendReplacement(sb, String.valueOf(ch));
    }
    mt.appendTail(sb);
    output[i] = sb.toString();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[b9, ab9, b9b9, 99b99a, a9, aA9]
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a very simple state machine. For each character you're looping through in the input string, keep track of a boolean. If the character is a 9, set the boolean to true. If the character is a letter add one to the letter and set the boolean to false. Then add the character to the output stringbuilder.

For input you use a `Reader`. For output use a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a 1 token look ahead parser technique.  Here is some psuedoish code:

```
for (int index = 0; index < buffer.length(); ++index)
{
  if (index < buffer.length() - 1)
  {
    if (buffer.charAt(index + 1) == '9')
    {
      char current = buffer.charAt(index) + 1; // this is probably not the best technique for this.
      buffer.setCharAt(index, current);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another solution is for example to use

```
StringUtils.indexOf(String str, char searchChar, int startPos)
```

in a way as Ernest Friedman-Hill pointed, take this as experimental example, not the most performant